# Failed to do authentication on physical phone. but it is run perfectly in my emulator

Tags: flutter, android-studio, usb-debugging

I have added firebase authentication to my flutter project. and when it is running on the emulator. it is perfectly run on it with authentication feature(Login and sign in both are working fine).

but when I use it with my real mobile phone using USB debugging. it is perfectly running, except authentication. every time it is failed to login and sign in with real device

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing both in Debug mode or are you doing Release mode on your device? If so, you might need to add the release SHA keys to Firebase.
`cd android ./gradlew :app:signingReport`

Comment: No I am testing my app on a  real device. instead of emulator.. in the emulator. app is running perfect.  but when I testing it with my device, it is always failed to perform the authentication part

Comment: I think we need more information to be able to help you then. At which point is it failing exactly? What error messages are you getting?

Comment: thank you for your support. I think it is an issue with my phone. it ran perfectly on another device. thank you